# How to use GraphQL subscriptions with Postgraphile?

Tags: express, graphql, express-graphql

I am very new to GraphQL, so maybe I am just missing something here.
i am currently creating an GraphQL endpoint of a Postgres SQL Database using the [PostGraphile](https://github.com/graphile/postgraphile)
I am able to perform queries, but i just found out about GraphQL Subscriptions and apparently PostGraphile supports it as explained [here](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/subscriptions/#enabling-with-an-express-app). Here its what I doing.

## Express Server

```
const express = require("express");
const { postgraphile, makePluginHook } = require("postgraphile");
const { default: PgPubsub } = require("@graphile/pg-pubsub");
const pluginHook = makePluginHook([PgPubsub]);


var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
let url = "postgres://postgres:docker@localhost:5432/dvdrental";
app.use(postgraphile(url,"public", {
  graphiql:true,
  pluginHook,
  subscriptions: true,
  simpleSubscriptions: true,
}));
app.listen(3000);
```

## Subscribing like

```
  subscription {
    listen(topic: "hello") {
      query {
        allPayments {
          nodes {
            customerId
            paymentDate
            nodeId
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

## Triggering like

```
postgres=# select pg_notify( 'postgraphile:hello', '{}' );
```

But I am not seeing anything on the graphiql response

## WebSocket/Network

Here it is what I get at the WebSocket/Network panel @Benjie.
The `{type:"ka}` actions appears to be fired in a random interval.

[image]

Comment: I noticed you’ve enabled CORS, but that only works for regular connections, not the websockets; perhaps the websocket connection is not working. Try using the network debug tools to see what’s going on: https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/debugging/#step-1-check-youre-requesting-what-you-think-youre-requesting

Comment: @Benjie removed cors middleware but WS connection does not shows anything.

Comment: @Benjie I have updated the question

Comment: @CESCO did you find this working? if yes then can you please provide me an example so it can helpful for me. I'm working on the same thing. thanks.